# Hibernate + JPA + Maven + Tomee + Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, tomcat

I'm struggling to set up a very small Rest API using JAX-RS + Hibernate + H2 as DB on tomcat 8.5.

After struggling so much with dependencies, testing Git sample , nothing worked so far.
So :

Pom is like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dataprovider</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jersey.version>2.36</jersey.version>
        <org.json.version>20210307</org.json.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.0.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <h2.version>[2.1.212,)</h2.version>
        <javax.persistence.version>2.2</javax.persistence.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>project</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Web.xml is like

```
<display-name>dataprovider</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<display-name>DataProvider</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DataProvider-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.provider.FutureApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DataProvider-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="dataproviderPU">
        
 
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
 
        <jta-data-source>jdbc:h2:mem:db1</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        </properties>
 
      
    </persistence-unit>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:db1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>
        <mapping class="com.demo.provider.entities.Lobby" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And finally , error is :

```
 Jun 24, 2022 4:42:41 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dataprovider]]
...
    Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Shared\Apps\tomeeWS\webapps\dataprovider: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f)


  ...
        Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Shared\Apps\tomeeWS\webapps\dataprovider: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f)
...
        Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f)
...
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f)
 ...
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @149ab762; javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2f686d1f)
```

I suppose there is mismatch between version but I'm not able to find one fully fonctionnal...

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks